# Is there a way in PHP to output the error log defined in the apache configuration?

Tags: php, apache

I created a PHP script to read the error log file in a customized visual format, but right now, I have the path to the error log file hard-coded in, which works fine for me, but I would like to find out if there's a way to pull the path to the error_log automatically so it can work on any server without further configuration.

Comment: So far, it seems like parsing phpinfo() to get the error log is going to be my best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ini_get](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) to obtain the error_log path in PHP.

```php
$error_log = ini_get('error_log');
```

Otherwise, you'd be relegated to using something like:

```php
<?php
ob_start();
phpinfo(INFO_CONFIGURATION);

$phpinfo = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

preg_match('#error_log</td><td\b[^>]*>(.*?)</td>#', $phpinfo, $matches);
$error_log = $matches[1];
```

Note that if there is no error_log set, `$error_log` will return:

```html
<i>no value</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pull it from the ErrorLog Directive

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog

Comment: i would parse the file to find the string.

Comment: just found this, should answer most of your questions: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get it in PHP is by installing something like [`ApacheAccessor`](http://pecl.php.net/package/ApacheAccessor). Wouldn't call it portable though, as I've seldomly seen it installed, but wildly guessing default paths is default distro's is about your only other option.